# Null vs Nil in database

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I am using an SQLite3 database with my rails app and am having a very frustrating time trying to solve this problem.

I want to populate check boxes in a different manner depending on if the form (_form.html.erb) is being rendered in update or in create so:

```
  <% if @foo.new_record? %>
    <% query = "association_id == nil" %>
  <% else %>
    <% query = "" %>
  <% end %>
```

and then I pass the query string to my check boxes

```
collection_check_boxes(:host, :association_ids, Association.where(query), :id, :name)
```

What this should do is give me all of the associations as check boxes for update and only ones that don't already have an association_id when creating.

If I replace the query with `:association_id=>nil` I will get the desired result for create. 
If I replace the query with `Association.all`, I get the result for update. 
I could just replicate all of my code manually in the check for new_record? but my code is already rather long and complicated and that would make it doubly so. So I wanted to just pass a string (query) to my where call. This is where I ran into trouble.

When I look in the rails console and make direct SQL queries I notice that returned files without an association_id will show up as `association_id: nil`. So I try to match to nil but that gives me an "unknown column: nil" error from SQL. When I try to match to the SQL NULL it doesn't find anything.

How is a nil attribute stored in the database and how do I query to find it using a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do

```
<% query = "association_id is null" %>

Association.where(:association_id => nil)
```

will be converted internally into a query like below

```
select * from associations where association_id is null
```

Comment: Thanks I tried basically every other variation except this one